# Eof not triggering

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a function where I get data from a DB, my test data set returns 6500 rows (I extracted the formatted SQL statement from the SQLText Variable and ran it as a test), but then when I run the following code Eof never triggers and I have seen over 100k rows imported.

```
ADOQuery := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
ADOQuery.ConnectionString := CONNECT_STRING;

// Build SQL Query 
SQLText :=   Format( 'Select  Temp.Serial, Temp.QCSample , Temp.Scrap , Temp.StationID , Temp.Defect , Temp.AddData , Temp2.Serial as Parent_Serial ' +
      'from TAB_ELEMENT as Temp ' + 

      'left join TAB_ELEMENT as Temp2 on  Temp.Parent_Id = Temp2.Element_Id ' + 
      'where Temp.Batch_ID = %d    and Temp.StationID = 0 ',[iSearchID]);

ADOQuery.SQL.Clear;   // Clear query of garbage values
ADOQuery.SQL.Text := SQLText; // Add query text to query module
ADOQuery.Open; 

// Handle Results
iIndexPos := 0; 
tDataImport.BeginUpdate;  

while not ADOQuery.Eof do
begin
    tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].Serial := ADOQuery.FieldByName('Serial').AsString;
    tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].QCStatus := ADOQuery.FieldByName('QCSample').AsBoolean;
    tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].Scrap := ADOQuery.FieldByName('Scrap').AsInteger;
    tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].StationID := ADOQuery.FieldByName('StationID').AsInteger;
    tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].Defect := ADOQuery.FieldByName('Defect').AsBoolean;
    tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].AddData := ADOQuery.FieldByName('AddData').AsString;
    tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].ParentSerial := ADOQuery.FieldByName('Parent_Serial').AsString;

    inc(iIndexPos);
end;
```

So in summery running this query with these parameters I expect 6500 rows, when I run this it never ends even after 100k+ rows are processed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Open()` places the cursor on the first record and sets `Eof` accordingly. You are not calling `Next()` to advance the cursor to the next record and update `Eof`, so you are processing the same record over and over:

```
ADOQuery.Open; 
while not ADOQuery.Eof do
begin
  //...
  ADOQuery.Next; // <-- add this!
end;
```

On a side note, you should be using a *parameterized query* instead of a formatted SQL query string.  It is safer, faster, and more efficient on the DB:

```
ADOQuery := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
ADOQuery.ConnectionString := CONNECT_STRING;

ADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'Select  Temp.Serial, Temp.QCSample , Temp.Scrap , Temp.StationID , Temp.Defect , Temp.AddData , Temp2.Serial as Parent_Serial ' +
  'from TAB_ELEMENT as Temp ' + 
  'left join TAB_ELEMENT as Temp2 on  Temp.Parent_Id = Temp2.Element_Id ' + 
  'where Temp.Batch_ID = :iSearchID and Temp.StationID = 0 ';

with ADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('iSearchID') do
begin
  DataType := ftInteger;
  Value := iSearchID;
end;

ADOQuery.Open; 
try
  iIndexPos := 0; 
  tDataImport.BeginUpdate;  
  try
    while not ADOQuery.Eof do
    begin
      tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].Serial := ADOQuery.FieldByName('Serial').AsString;
      tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].QCStatus := ADOQuery.FieldByName('QCSample').AsBoolean;
      tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].Scrap := ADOQuery.FieldByName('Scrap').AsInteger;
      tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].StationID := ADOQuery.FieldByName('StationID').AsInteger;
      tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].Defect := ADOQuery.FieldByName('Defect').AsBoolean;
      tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].AddData := ADOQuery.FieldByName('AddData').AsString;
      tDataImport.Items[iIndexPos].ParentSerial := ADOQuery.FieldByName('Parent_Serial').AsString;
      inc(iIndexPos);
      ADOQuery.Next; 
    finally
      tDataImport.EndUpdate;  
    end;
  end;
finally
  ADOQuery.Close; 
end;
```